# Go to implementation action in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I got a problem: when I want to go to implementation, I have to press ⌥⌘B on MacOs, but when I click on the Implemented method icon, it does not work. Before I had updated, I had that feature.
How can I return the ability to click on the icon and see the implementation?

[Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT2Q1.png)

Comment: Try to clear the IDE caches. (File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart) See if disabling third-party plugins help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html

Comment: If the problem remains, contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and record a short screencast illustrating the problem

Comment: Thank you for the link, by the way I tried to disable plugins and to invalidate caches — nothing helped.